# Is it possible to use the parallelism provided by the Stream API to call a fixed number of mutually independent methods?

Tags: java, multithreading, java-stream

I have a Java class where I am using the parallelism provided by the [`Stream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html) API. This serves my purpose fine because most of my data input is a stream. There is one place, however, where the code is like this:

```
void aMethod() {
    double[] a = methodA();
    double[] b = methodB();
    double[] c = methodC();
    doSomething(a, b, c);
}

doSomething(double[] a, double[] b, double[] c) {
    // concatenates the three arrays, converts to parallel stream, and does stuff
}
```

The three calls to `methodA`, `methodB` and `methodC` can be concurrent. Is there a way to use the `Stream` API to these run in parallel?

Comment: Look into completable futures.

Comment: Looks like a job for `ForkJoinPool`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily create a (parallel) stream of method references that act as `Supplier` of `double[]` arrays. These can then be mapped to their return values, and collected into a list. Roughly sketched here:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.function.Supplier;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class ParallelStreamMethods {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Stream<Supplier<double[]>> s = Stream.of(
            ParallelStreamMethods::methodA, 
            ParallelStreamMethods::methodB, 
            ParallelStreamMethods::methodC);

        List<double[]> result = 
            s.parallel().map(r -> r.get()).collect(Collectors.toList());

        doSomething(result.get(0), result.get(1), result.get(2));
    }

    private static double[] methodA() {
        return getValues("methodA");
    }

    private static double[] methodB() {
        return getValues("methodB");
    }

    private static double[] methodC() {
        return getValues("methodC");
    }

    private static double[] getValues(String name) {
        System.out.println("Enter "+name);
        try {
            int n = 1000 + (int)(Math.random() * 500);
            Thread.sleep(n);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Exit "+name);
        return new double[1000];
    }

    private static void doSomething(double[] a, double[] b, double[] c) {
        System.out.println("Doing something with "+a+", "+b+", "+c);
    }
}
```

Note that the collector is only used to show the basic idea. Depending on how you intend to process the results, this could be solved differently. However, the comment

```
// concatenates the three arrays, converts to parallel stream, and does stuff
```

sounds a bit dubious. You might want to consider using `DoubleStream`s instead of arrays, and then `flatMap` them to create a larger `DoubleStream`.

Comment: The comment was a quick write-up to illustrate the core issue of my question (that everywhere else I can form streams in an obvious way). In my actual code, I am operating on my own objects, not primitives. You are absolutely right, though. For int, double, etc., I should be doing what you have suggested.

Comment: @ChthonicProject Note, however, that (until now) I don't see a particular reason to solve this with streams. As suggested in the comments, a thread pool and some `Future`s could be the more ... idiomatic way to solve this.

Comment: Thank you Marco13. I am realizing this too. I am quite new to any kind of multi-threaded programming, and often go down the improper path first. I've been reading up about `Future`s, and will, hopefully, learn it soon enough :-)